# JPA/Hibernate child subset of parent set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Lets assume we have the following entity associations:

```
    public class Classroom {


        @OneToMany(mappedBy="classroom")
        private Set<Session> sessions;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="classroom")
        private Set<Instructor> instructors;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="classroom")
        private Set<Student> students;
    }


    public class Session {

        @ManyToOne
        private Classroom classroom;

        @ManyToMany
        private Set<Instructors> instructors;

        @ManyToMany
        private Set<Student> students;

    }

    public class Student {

        @ManyToOne
        private Classroom classroom;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
        private Set<Session> sessions;
    }

    public class Instructor {

        @ManyToOne
        private Classroom classroom;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy="instructors")
        private Set<Session> sessions;

    }
```

The general idea is that Sessions belong to a particular Classroom and the Students+Instructors that belong to that Session should be a subset of the ones belonging to the Classroom.

I could handle this at the Service layer, but is there a better way to handle this directly with JPA?

Comment: I think that you don't need to declare the relationships in every entity.
Wouldn't be more efficient to map the session to a classroom and the instructors with the students to the session?

Comment: can you describe how you are  handling this at the Service layer???